# Unresolved dependencies in Akka http

Tags: akka

I keep getting unresolved dependencies with the code below. Any clue what I can do to clear the error?

```
name := "AkkaDemo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val scalaTestVersion = "3.0.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

lazy val akkademoService = project.settings (libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"% "3.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.16",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.14"

)).
  dependsOn(instanceConfig)


lazy val instanceConfig = project

lazy val AkkaDemo =  project.in(file(".")).aggregate(instanceConfig, akkademoService)
```

Here is the sbt output for the sbt run:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] 
Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.4.16: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j;2.3.14: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: What dependencies are unresolved? When do you get the error? Can you expect anyone to provide a solution for a question you didn't ask?

Comment: Could you please post actual sbt output?

Comment: Something is not right - sbt file declares scalaVersion 2.11, but it tries to resolve akka-actor for scala 2.10. Could you please post entire sbt output (preferably to some external storage service, like github gist or pastebin)? Also, could you please tag me explicitly when you do so, because question updates are not automatically sent as notifications.

Comment: Hi, I pushed the code on github, and opened an issue, you can check them both at https://github.com/kenadet/akkademo https://github.com/kenadet/akkademo/issues/1 . Thanks very much. @J0HN

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding build.sbt with the scalaversion to use to each module. Apparently each module, without a build.sbt specifying the version to use, default to 2.10.